# VB Date and Datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering what was the proper way to create a If statement for if the datetimepicker date is greater than 2 weeks from the current date.

I was thinking something along the lines of

If (datetimepicker.value > DateTimeInterval.Day(14))

but I am not sure the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to subtract the current date from the picker date.  To get a TimeSpan:

```
    If DateTimePicker1.Value.Date - DateTime.Now.Date > TimeSpan.FromDays(14) Then
        '' It's more than 2 weeks
    End If
```

Comment: so should I use 14 or is there a way with where it would exactly be 2 weeks....maybe using   DateInterval.Weekday? trying to figure out the best way

Comment: What part of the world do you live in where 2 weeks isn't 14 days?

Comment: Why did you comment ''Its more than 2 weeks than???? I thought that maybe it wasn't exactly 2 weeks, meaning the time was calculated differently like 12:00 when it started...

Comment: If you want "2 weeks or more" then use the >= operator in the if statement.